# Image is cutoff with Shiny/Flexdashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, conditional-statements, flexdashboard

I need to conditionally display a series of instructions and a corresponding image. I was unable to get both to display using `renderUI` (I believe this is [due to a bug](https://community.rstudio.com/t/conditionally-display-local-image-in-flexdashboard/172833) in `flexdashboard`).

I solved this problem by including both a `renderUI` and `renderImage` within separate divs in the same tab.

However, I have a new problem: the image is getting cut off. Shiny/Flexdashboard doesn't seem to realize that the image is larger than the screen.

I can force it to add a scroll bar by adding some css, but the scroll bar doesn't activate because it doesn't realize that the image is off the screen. Is there different css I should be using?

Reprex below:

````
---
title: "MyApp"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
=====================================

```{r}
selectInput("input_type", 
            label = "Select an input",
            choices = list(" "=1,
                           "Input 1" = 2,
                           "Input 2" = 3))
```


MyApp
=====================================

Row {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### renderUI 

<div>
```{r}
renderUI({
  
  input_type <- input$input_type
  
  if (input_type == 1) {
    HTML('Welcome to my app! Here are some instructions about how to use it. 
A helpful image will appear when you select an input.')} 
  
  else if (input_type == 2) {
    HTML('Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.')
  } 
  
  else if (input_type == 3) {
    HTML('Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.<br>
         Here are some instructions.')
  }
  
})
```
</div>

<div>
```{r}
renderImage({
  input_type <- input$input_type
  if (input$input_type==1){
    return(list(
      src = "no_image.png",
      contentType = "image/png"
    ))
  }
  else if (input$input_type == 2) { 
    return(list(
      src = "Myimage1.png",
      contentType = "image/png",
      width=400,
      height=500
      ))
    } 
  else if (input$input_type == 3) {
    return(list(
      src = "Myimage1.png",
      filetype = "image/png"
      ))
    }
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)

```
</div>
````

[image]